# get data into schema by id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have two schema i would like to get some info from another schema for example (firstName, lastName) from the userSchema by id that i would provide when adding new comment on the CommentsSchema

```
const CommentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  commentText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  time: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population) to get data from a referenced collection.

First you need to change comments schema to set up a reference to the User model.
You may need to change ref value, if you used a different user model name when you applied `mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)`.

```js
const CommentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true
  },
  commentText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  time: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Let's say you have this user in users collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5e312d5cab2e5028b8865be3",
    "userName": "Mongoose",
    "firstName": "Buk",
    "lastName": "Lau",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And this comment from this user:

```
{
    "_id": "5e312d9cab2e5028b8865be4",
    "userId": "5e312d5cab2e5028b8865be3",
    "commentText": "this is a comment",
    "time": "2020-01-29T07:00:44.126Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Now you can access the user info from comment like this:

```js
router.get("/comments/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Comment.findById(req.params.id).populate("userId");
  res.send(result);
});
```

The result will be like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e312d9cab2e5028b8865be4",
    "userId": {
        "_id": "5e312d5cab2e5028b8865be3",
        "userName": "Mongoose",
        "firstName": "Buk",
        "lastName": "Lau",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "commentText": "this is a comment",
    "time": "2020-01-29T07:00:44.126Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help .

Comment: @BukLau you are welcome, please don’t forget to accept as answer.

Comment: of course just i want to ask is there any possible to get all the comments of a movie. so every-time im saving a comment i did save with it the id of the user so i can get his info when i want to get all the comments of that movie.
```const CommentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true
  },
movieId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  commentText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  time: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Comment: @BukLau I am surw that it is possible. It would be better if you can ask a new question. I will help if I can.

Comment: i did make it work 
```const result = await CommentsModel.find({ movieId: "tt6923858" }).populate(
      "userId"
    );```

Comment: @BukLau great, so you understood how populate works.